# How to initialise a string from NSData in Swift

Tags: string, swift, cocoa, nsdata

I have been trying to initialise a string from `NSData` in Swift.

In the [NSString Cocoa Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:) Apple is saying you have to use this:

```
 init(data data: NSData!, encoding encoding: UInt)
```

However Apple did not include any example for usage or where to put the `init`.

I am trying to convert the following code from Objective-C to Swift

```
NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I have been trying a lot of possible syntaxes such as the following (of course it did not work):

```
var string:NSString!
string = init(data: fooData,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 228, accepted):

This is how you should initialize the `NSString`:

Swift 2.X or older

```
let datastring = NSString(data: fooData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Swift 3 or newer:

```
let datastring = NSString(data: fooData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

[This doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_266) explains the syntax.

Comment: Note that you don’t need to repeat “data” and “encoding” like that.

Comment: How can you do that what UInt is a constructor? It's asking me to add brackets.

Comment: Should be `let datastring = NSString(data: fooData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Comment: Is it possible to convert `NSData` directly into a Swift `String` (instead of an `NSString`)?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale var swiftString = NSString(data: NSData!, encoding: UInt) as! String that's all

Comment: @MattDiPasquale Ignore the above forced cast; `String` is an `NSString`... all of these should be:
`var datastring = String(data: someData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Comment: @JRaymond NSLog would reject it as argument if you don't cast it.

Answer (score 283):

This is the implemented code needed:

### **in Swift 3.0:**

```
var dataString = String(data: fooData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

or just

```
var dataString = String(data: fooData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Older swift version:

**in Swift 2.0:**

```
import Foundation

var dataString = String(data: fooData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

**in Swift 1.0:**

```
var dataString = NSString(data: fooData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Swift 2 has a different way of doing this

Comment: Added a Swift 2.0 version as well now

Comment: Would you happen to know the Swift 3.0 way? `error: use of unresolved identifier 'NSUTF8StringEncoding'`

Comment: Added a Swift 3.0 version as well. Damn, Apple like changing stuff!

Comment: Does swift have an "#ifdef" to make the code support both versions?

Comment: There is #if #else #elseif, try those

Comment: You have to compile against a specific version of Swift, so your code will all be written against either 2.x or 3.x. Also, note with the 3.0 version you can shorten it by using `var dataString = String(data: fooData, encoding: .utf8)`.

Answer (score 15):

### Swift 2.0

It seems that Swift 2.0 has actually introduced the `String(data:encoding:)` as an String extension when you import `Foundation`. I haven't found any place where this is documented, weirdly enough.

### (pre Swift 2.0) Lightweight extension

Here's a copy-pasteable little extension without using `NSString`, let's cut the middle-man.

```
import Foundation

extension NSData
{
    var byteBuffer : UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8> { get { return UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(self.bytes), count: self.length) }}
}

extension String
{
    init?(data : NSData, encoding : NSStringEncoding)
    {
        self.init(bytes: data.byteBuffer, encoding: encoding)
    }
}

// Playground test
let original = "Nymphs blitz quick vex dwarf jog"
let encoding = NSASCIIStringEncoding

if let data = original.dataUsingEncoding(encoding)
{
    String(data: data, encoding: encoding)
}
```

This also give you access to `data.byteBuffer` which is a sequence type, so all those cool operations you can do with sequences also work, like doing a `reduce { $0 &+ $1 }` for a checksum.

### Notes

In my previous edit, I used this method:

```
var buffer = Array<UInt8>(count: data.length, repeatedValue: 0x00)
data.getBytes(&buffer, length: data.length)
self.init(bytes: buffer, encoding: encoding)
```

The problem with this approach, is that I'm creating a copy of the information into a new array, thus, I'm duplicating the amount of bytes (specifically: `encoding size * data.length`)

Answer (score 4):

Since the third version of Swift you can do the following:

```
let desiredString = NSString(data: yourData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

simialr to what Sunkas advised.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Foundation
var string = NSString(data: NSData?, encoding: UInt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another answer based on extensions (boy do I miss this in Java):

```
extension NSData {
    func toUtf8() -> String? {
        return String(data: self, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
let data : NSData = getDataFromEpicServer()
let string : String? = data.toUtf8()
```

Note that the string is optional, the initial `NSData` may be unconvertible to Utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Objective - C

```
NSData *myStringData = [@"My String" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSString *myStringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myStringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"My string value: %@",myStringFromData);
```

Swift

```
//This your data containing the string
   let myStringData = "My String".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

   //Use this method to convert the data into String
   let myStringFromData =  String(data:myStringData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

   print("My string value:" + myStringFromData!)
```

http://objectivec2swift.blogspot.in/2016/03/coverting-nsdata-to-nsstring-or-convert.html