# Reading Websites in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, api

I am trying to read data from my API. I am not using JSON data because the API doesn't return an array, just a line of text. Anyways, I am using the following code to read the text from the API.

```
func contactVetApi(url:String){

    let nsUrl = NSURL(string:url)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsUrl!){
        (data, response, error) in
        print(data)

    }

    task.resume()

}
```

I am calling this function in the ViewDidLoad function of my ViewController file. As you can see, it takes a parameter that is a string. The parameter is the URL to read. It then translates the string into a NSUrl so it can be used with the sharedSession. I then initialize the shared session and create a data task with that url. I then print out the data it returns. The only issue is that the output isn't what I am expecting. What I am expecting is for it to say, "Future home of something quite cool." Although, this is what I am getting.

> Optional(<46757475 72652068 6f6d6520 6f662073 6f6d6574 68696e67 20717569 74652063 6f6f6c>)
>   Optional(<46757475 72652068 6f6d6520 6f662073 6f6d6574 68696e67 20717569 74652063 6f6f6c>)

I need help figuring out why it is printing that out instead of what I am expecting. In case it is needed, the api url is http://apis.wilsonfamily5.org/vet/about.php. Before anybody asks though, I did add into the info.plist file the disabling of the iOS 9 app transport security. If you need any extra information to help me solve this problem, I would be more then happy to give it to you. I want to thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to convert the data to a String or NSString, currently you receive NSData and print that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24023372/2442804

Comment: Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently are printing a `NSData` object, which will always look like that jibberish. What you actually want however is to convert the `NSData` to a `NSString` or `String` to create a human readable form:

```
var dataAsString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24023372/2442804).