# NSData to String in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, string, nsdata

My NSData length is 20 bytes. Like

> <7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF>

But every time when it runs to this code would return nil.

```
let stringData: String = NSString(data: nsdata, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
```

Can anybody help me solve this question?

Thanks.

Comment: That data is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. What result do you expect?

Comment: You can make this with String init not NSString init
[Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29408376/4687211)

Comment: from where are you getting this `NSData`? something wrong with encoding I guess

Comment: I want the result like "7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.description()` on nsdata variable to get exact same string as above: "<7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF 7FFF7FFF>":

```
nsdata.description()
```

but is that really what you want? Maybe you want to parse it or something like that? For that kind of solution you will need to provide more deatils.

Converted from hex to string I get: "ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ" so I assume that this is some kind of message that you want to decode.

EDIT:

You could extract bytes into the array with:

```
Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), count: data.length))
```

Comment: Why downvote? Is this incorrect or doesn't provide any kind of solution for given information?

Comment: I don't give you the downvote. I want the result like "7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF".

Comment: PS. I know its not you :)