# iOS Swift 3 create URLSession extension for synchronous and asynchronous request

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm about to create an extension for `URLSession` in Swift 3 to create synchronous and asynchronous request. Here is my implementation

```
extension URLSession {
    func sendSynchronousRequest(request: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        let task = self.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            completionHandler(data,response,error)
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    }

    func sendAsynchronousRequest(request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        let task = self.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            completionHandler(data, response, error)
        }
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
}
```

I have Xcode suggest me to insert the @escaping to the function. I don't know whether the implementation is correct

I also have warning at this line:

[image]

Anyone know how to correct the extension?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this implementation but in swift1/2 can't remember. This is not my own. But i rewrote it in swift3. I just can't remember where i found it :/

```
func synchronousDataTaskWithURL(url: URL) -> (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) {
    var data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    dataTask(with: url) {
        data = $0; response = $1; error = $2
        semaphore.signal()
        }.resume()

    semaphore.wait()

    return (data, response, error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. How can we use the function? for example to print out the data and then execute another serial task? is the asynchronous function correct with @escaping?

Comment: URLSession already has a Async function URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: <URL>, completionHandler: <(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void>)

Comment: thanks so we can use the default async no need to wrap? I tried to use the synchronous with let data = result.0
        
        let stringData = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8). but have error nil. Is that the correct way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023253/how-to-initialise-a-string-from-nsdata-in-swift

Comment: there is not need to wrap it

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's the properway to make a synchronous network call? (only process when call finish)?

Comment: In general I think it is a bad idea to use synchronized http requests. But if you really need too this is the way to do it